# What to do with CATextLayer to have the same font displayed as the system font in UILabel?

Tags: objective-c, swift, catextlayer

When I use `UILabel`, I set the system font as:

```
label.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(18, weight: UIFontWeightMedium)
```

Now I try to use `CATextLayer` and I searched online and found out that the system font for iOS 9 is `San Francisco` and the font name is `.SFUIText-Medium`, so I try to set the font name as:

```
textLayer = CATextLayer() 
textLayer.font = CTFontCreateWithName(".SFUIText-Medium", 18, nil)
```

However, the fonts shown on the device screen are not the same for `UILabel` & `CATextLayer` as explained above. What is the correct font name to be used in `CATextLayer` here so that I can have exactly the same font displayed as the `UILabel`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since iOS 7.0, `UIFont` and `CTFont` have been “toll-free-bridged”. This means that you can treat a `UIFont` as `CTFont`, and vice versa. Thus:

```
let view = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 100))
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

let layer = CATextLayer()
layer.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(18, weight: UIFontWeightMedium)
layer.string = "Hello"
layer.frame = view.bounds
layer.foregroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
view.layer.addSublayer(layer)

XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.liveView = view
print(layer.font)
```

Result:

[image: screen shot]

```
Optional(<UICTFont: 0x7f904bf38960> font-family: ".SFUIText-Medium"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 18.00pt)
```

Comment: Great! Now the font looks the same, however it seems the heights are different. I use `sizeToFit()` via UILabel to get the height for 2 lines of text. When I set this height to the CATextLayer that uses the same font and font size, it only shows one line of text and get truncated.

Comment: After more testing, there indeed some difference in the height. I add about 5% to the UILabel's height, then it's alright.

Comment: that height difference is insanity - so bizarre

Comment: to have the same fontSize need add
textLayer.fontSize = font.pointSize